# Rails Nested Form - Creating a new Meeting from Club

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, nested-form-for

I have a `User`, `Meeting`, and `Club` Model.

A `User` has_many :user_clubs, has_many :clubs, :through => :user_clubs.

A `Club` has_many :user_clubs, has_many :users, :through => :user_clubs, and has_many :meetings

A `Meeting` belongs_to :club, and has_many :users

The trouble I'm facing is creating a new meeting through the nested route: 
`http://localhost:3000/clubs/1/meetings/new`.

When I attempt to create the meeting I'm getting the validation error "Club must exist." I understand that this can be overridden because the belongs_to association is requiring Club. However, I should not need to override it - as EVERY meeting should belong to a club. I just don't know how to correctly solve the error.

My routes are:

```
resources :users
resources :clubs do
  resources :meetings, only: [:show, :index, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
end

resources :meetings, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

My Meetings#new action looks like:

```
def new
  @club = Club.find(params[:club_id])
  @meeting = Meeting.new
end
```

and Meetings#create:

```
def create
  binding.pry
  @meeting = Meeting.new(meeting_params)
  if @meeting.save
    binding.pry
    redirect_to club_path, notice: "Meeting was succesfully created."
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

My Meetings `new` template is using `form_for(@meeting) do |f|`. How do I pass the `club` that the validation requires to Meetings#create? The flow is: 
User show page *clicks club* > Club show page *clicks button to create new meeting* > Meetings#new page *types in name, description, time and clicks create* > Meetings#index page 
I'm unable to get past the Meetings#new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The answer was in my `form_for`. I needed to change it to:

```
<%= form_for [@club, @meeting] do |f| %>
```